# How do I merge with --no-ff in SmartGit/hg?

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, smartgit

If you want to keep track of the moment you started a new feature-branch you can use

```
git merge --no-ff -m "merged feature-branch" some-feature-branch
```

As described [here](http://www.adamfranco.com/2010/12/12/git-tip-grouping-feature-branch-commits-when-merging/). How can I achieve this using the [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/) GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using **Branch|Merge** from the project window and SmartGit/Hg detects that a fast-forward merge will be possible, it will ask you whether to do so. The same happens when using **Branch|Merge** from the Log.